# Youtube api3. How to get playlist id without using API_KEY?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying get it by request: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId={my_playlist_id}` but always have an error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
        "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
    }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Could it be that dayliLimit for unauth users is set to 0? And is it possible use this request without api_key like in api v2

(something like that `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/{playlist_id}`)?

Answer (score 1):

The default quota is 50 Million QPD and no it's not possible to get playlist id without using API key. You can check how much quota you have by going to developer console -> APIs -> YouTube Data API v3 -> Quota

Your query worked fine for me without any errors. I entered a random playlist ID and my own API key

Comment: so, why they didn`t say anything about using api key to get playlist id here [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#uploaded_videos) ?